# Java login form with SQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to develop a login form with Java and MySQL (WAMP server and Netbeans), but it does not work. When I fulfill the form with the right information and send it, it always shows me that the user is inexistent.

This is the first class Connector.java:

```
package BDD; 
//
public class Connector {
private Connection conn;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public Connection getConnection (){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println(e);  
    }
    try {
        conn= (Connection) 

    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:
    //localhost:3306/ges_article","root","");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.err.println(e);//afficher erreur
    }
     finally{
        return conn;
    }
   }

public ResultSet searchQuery (String sql){
    try {
        getConnection();
        st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
       System.err.println(e);

    }
    return rs;
}
 }
```

And this is the second class Authentifcation.java:

```
//
public class Authentification extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  //                
private void initComponents() {
   //
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        Connector db = new Connector();
        String user, password;
        user = jTextFieldLogin.getText();
        password =  jTextFieldPassword.getText();
        ResultSet rs = db.searchQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='"+user+"' AND password='"+password+"'" );
        if(rs.isBeforeFirst()){       
            System.out.println("utilisateur existant");
        }
          else{
            System.out.println("utilisateur inexistant");
              }
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}   
 //
}
```

Comment: Consider reading about [SQL injection](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/sql-injection-in-java-application.html). Your application is vulnerable. Please also show the contents of your `user` table and the input you provide in `jTextFieldLogin`.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.isBeforeFirst()` is where the `ResultSet` would start, I think you want `rs.next()`.

I'd also encourage the use of [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
Connector db = new Connector();
try (Connection conn = db.getConnection()) {
    String user, password;
    user = jTextFieldLogin.getText();
    password = jTextFieldPassword.getText();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login=? AND password=?");
    ps.setString(1, user);
    ps.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("utilisateur existant");
    } else {
        System.out.println("utilisateur inexistant");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: it didnot  find  data from the database and always show me "utilisateur inexistant"